# mySQL optimize group by Statement with Subquerys

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

i have a SQL Statement which looks like:

```
select id, CIDs, COLOR, XT, MP, Name, concat(PIDs,",",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id)) as PIDs, IFNULL(Name,id) as unqName from ( 
select id, CIDs, COLOR, XT, MP, Name, concat(PIDs,",",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id)) as PIDs, IFNULL(MP,id) as unqMP from (
select id, CIDs, COLOR, XT, MP, Name, concat(PIDs,",",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id)) as PIDs, IFNULL(XT,id) as unqXT from ( 
select id, CIDs, COLOR, XT, MP, Name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id) as PIDs, IFNULL(COLOR,id) as unqCOLOR from Performance group by unqCOLOR 
) m group by unqXT 
) x group by unqMP 
) y group by unqName
```

i need to trim the Performance Details and get the PIDs, it works.
But i get duplicate PIDs (4 times), are there any Performance optimizations?
To get the SQL Statement faster executed and the PIDs unique?

```
mysql> select count(*) from Performance;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   243484 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Executed the SQL Statement takes:

```
Query OK, 137771 rows affected (43.54 sec)
```

**edit**:
SQLFiddle Link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2b12/1/0

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. This is a terrible query. Good that you've shown us what you've tried, but now let's go back to basics. Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT. Oh, and let's forget about all that GROUP_CONCAT stuff for the time being too and just return a simple ordered (and ungrouped/unconcatenated) result.

Comment: okay, just a moment ;)

Comment: @Strawberry: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2b12/1/0 here is an example ;) the result looks fine, but the PIDs are not unique and on much data it will be slow :/

Comment: So, it's not the desired result?